# Complex Aggregations in SQL

Tags: sql

All I want to do is get a data set that shows me how many orders were placed and how many calls were made for each order. I also need the date of the calls and the date of the order, in the same table. The table is 10M+ rows, so aggregation of the result set is essential for analysis. **The only analysis I want to do is the sum of calls/the total orders, and to be able to see how many support_tickets were generated from orders within an order range, up to a call_date**. Very simple, but surprisingly complex to code up. Here is my attempt. I have also tried to change the below into a union, but still get wrong aggregate results.

```
-- The Query:-
SELECT
category_name
count(order_code)
order_date
sum(support_ticket_call)
call_date
FROM 
(Select distinct name, order_code, order_date from table1) b
left join 
(select count(call_ids), call_date FROM table2) b
on b.order_ID_code = a.order_id_code
group by category_name, order_date, call_date
```

Whenever there are no support_ticket_calls, the call_date is NULL, as you would expect. The count of orders is like 60,000 though, which is different from the usual 12 or so in the rest of the result set. I know something is wrong with this query, but It's driving me insane trying to solve it, literally all day so far.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to answer this question without sample data and expected results, but the comment was getting too long.

You have several problems with your current query.  First you need to `join` on the date fields by using `on` criteria.  You also need to add `group by` to those queries that use aggregation.  Finally, where does `support_ticket_call` come from?  Can I presume it's the alias for the `count(call_ids)`?

Something like this should get you close:

```
SELECT
    a.name as category_name,
    count(a.order_code),
    sum(b.support_ticket_call),
    a.order_date as call_date
FROM 
    (Select distinct name, order_code, order_date 
     from table1) a
left join 
    (select count(call_ids) as support_ticket_call, call_date 
     from table2 group by call_date) b on a.order_date = b.call_date
group by a.name, a.order_date
```

Comment: Firstly, the call date and order date are not in both tables. Also, the call date does not happen on the same day as the order